# Passing a long type variable from one activity and receiving it in another activity and displaying it in a TextView

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I m trying to pass a long type varible from one activity to another and then show it in a TextView.
I used this code in the firstActivity to get and transfer the variable:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                    long currentId = (long) values.get(position).getId();

                    Intent edit_acc = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditAccount.class);
                    edit_acc.putExtra("data_id", currentId);
                    startActivity(edit_acc);

               }});
```

And i used this to get the variable in the EditAccount Activity:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
        int id =(int) intent.getExtras().getInt("data_id");
        TextView txt_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_value_id); 
        txt_id.setText(id);
```

There seems to be a bug in the code which i can't figure out..
PLease help.
Thanks in advance,
Waiting for your reply...

Comment: what is the problem ? post logcat

Comment: what is the bug ? means what is the problem in passing data ?

Comment: `int id =(int) intent.getExtras().getLong("data_id");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.**

```
int id =(int) intent.getExtras().getLong("data_id");
```

**2.**
As your id of int type so you need type casting in `txt_id.setText(id);`

so your code should be:

**either**

```
    txt_id.setText(""+id);
```

**or**

```
    txt_id.setText(Integer.valueOf(id).toString());
```

Comment: Im gonna mark your answer correct after 7 minutes from now :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this so you can get properly.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            long id = arg0.getItemIdAtPosition(arg2);
            Log.v("id", id+"");

        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Better use this...In your second Activity declare one variable like this...

public static long dataUse;

Now in first activity

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                    long currentId = (long) values.get(position).getId();
                    EditAccount.dataUsage = currentId;
                    Intent edit_acc = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditAccount.class);
                    startActivity(edit_acc);

               }});
```

Now in second Activity,

```
txt_id.setText(dataUse);
```

Comment: Not better... In fact it is a bad idea